# htaccess 301 redirect blog/username to user/username

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know this must have been answered on here before so I apologize in advance, but despite my numerous searches - I couldn't find a suitable answer.

I have an url, for instance: www.domain.com/blog/username which I'd like to redirect to www.domain.com/users/username

Another example:

```
www.domain.com/blog/joe-blogs becomes www.domain.com/users/joe-blogs 
www.domain.com/blog/bill jones becomes www.domain.com/users/bill jones
www.domain.com/blog/adam becomes www.domain.com/users/adam
```

I've tried:

```
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)$ ./users/$1
```

But it's not quite right and results in a 404.

I also want www.domain.com/blog to redirect to www.domain.com/users

Comment: try changing  ./users/$1 to /users/$1.. or users/$1

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^forum/blog/(.+?)/?$ /users/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Almost got it working, thanks to this comment. I had to add R=301 in the last square brackets. However, the initial question was actually a little inaccurate. The directory should be www.domain.com/forum/blog/{username} to www.domain.com/users/{username} - how could I change your rule to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With .htaccess files, you can do mod_rewrite which lets you do a bait and switch with webpages and also you can set up custom error documents. you can do a plain redirect by using a simple call to header() in PHP. place this on the top of orig. weppage(s) and set the target webpage:

```
    <?php header('Location:http://www.somesite.com/users/username'); ?>
```

Comment: The reason that I need to do this using htaccess (and then move to vhosts) is that the original pages will be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **`RedirectPermanent`**

```
RedirectPermanent /blog/username /users/username
```

If the above doesn't work..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /blog/username /users/username [R=302]
RewriteRule /blog /users [R=302]
```

Comment: I don't want the username to be hardcoded though, so it should be a variable. Eg blog/joe-blogs becomes users/joe-blogs

Comment: Hmm you should mention such details before posting the question. No problem.